# Django - How to create many to one relation

Tags: python, django

In my application there is many-to-one relation, such as one teacher can teach more than one subject. So in admin panel I can't simulate it. Can't add more than one subject: [image: Screenshot]

Here are my codes:

models.py:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    credit = models.IntegerField()

class Teacher(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    chair = models.ForeignKey(Chair, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    academic_degree = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has extremely great support for a attribute related to many other attribute. In your case a single subject could be taught by multiple teacher and multiple teacher can teach single subject. In order to define relationship like above you can leverage ManyToMany relation(this facilate many subject getting associated with single teacher). In case you need one to Many relationship you can use ManyToOne relation.

```
subject = models.ManyToManyField(subject)
```

Comment: Please update your answer to include some explanations and context. Code-only answers are considered low quality.

Comment: @h4z3 Code-only answers *aren't* considered very low quality, but some context would be really good.

Comment: @FZs Never said anything about "very". ;) Got this answer in Low Quality queue, so it was automatic filter who first considered it low quality, so more content in the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @h4z3 I thought, you've flagged it as "*Very Low Quality*", and that was the reason it ended up in the queue...

Comment: @FZs Nah, that was my response to it being in the queue. Though, I skipped it after commenting because it's neither "ok" nor bad, so maybe it showed up in the queue later as well.

Comment: @h4z3 As this tries to answer the question, you can click Looks OK (even if it doesn't look OK, but shouldn't be deleted)...

Answer (score 1):

You've got it reversed. `ForeignKey` is *Many-to-One* with *Many* being the instances of model where it is defined; you've declared `ForeignKey` on the `Teacher` model to `Subject` model, which means "many teachers can teach only a single subject" -- which should be the other way around.

So define the `ForeignKey` to the `Teacher` model on the `Subject` model. And also do the same for other similar ones.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it other way around

You should put the `'ForeighKey'` relation in `'Subject'` model instead of `'Teacher'`

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    credit = models.IntegerField()
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is assuming there is only 1 teacher for a subject. Teacher can have multiple subjects. If there are many teachers for same subject then you need to use `ManyToMany()` relation.